# How to create a computed function in vue.js which consumes a global list and the current item of a foreach?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following HTML code with vue.js bindings. The code shows a list of items in a table.

```
<table id="test-vue">
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <td>
            <input type="text" v-model="item.foreignId" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <div v-if="canApproveItem(item, foreignValues)">
               // UI allowing to approve the item
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The Vue app is defined as:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#test-vue",
    data: function() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    foreignId: '4943',
                }
            ],
            foreignValues: [
                { id: '2424', canApprove: false },
                { id: '4943', canApprove: true }
            ],
    computed: {
        canApproveItem: function(item, foreignValues) {
            let foreign = foreignValues(obj => {
                return obj.id === item.foreignId;
            });
            if (foreign) {
                return foreign;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The goal is to show the approve UI only for items which links to a "foreign" whose `canApprove` property is set to `true`. The user can edit the `foreignId` and the user interface should reflect the user-made change of the `foreignId` values.

If I run the above, the `item` argument of the `canApproveItem` function is the `Vue` object and `foreignValues` is undefined. I also get a `Error in render: "TypeError: canApproveItem is not a function"` error in the console.

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a method. You shouldn't pass in `foreignValues`, as you can access that from the method itself.

```
<table id="test-vue">
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <td>
            <input type="text" v-model="item.foreignId" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <div v-if="canApproveItem(item)">
               // UI allowing to approve the item
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and

```
new Vue({
   // data and stuff here...
   methods: {
        canApproveItem(item) {
            return this.foreignValues.findIndex(obj => obj.id === item.foreignId) !== -1;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. I have just added that I also get a `Error in render: "TypeError: canApproveItem is not a function"` error in the console which might be more insightful.

Comment: it doesnt work because you cant pass arguments to computed properties. You have to return a function with your params from the computed property. Also, if you need to use `this` inside the function, bind it before returning it. `var vm = this`

Comment: oh, i'm thinking of methods. i think changing that should work.